# Address Reuse for Multisig Address

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, multi-signature, bitcoin-core-development, address-reuse

It is De facto standard that address should not be reused, and even Bitcoin officially emphasis address should not be reused. Does the same condition apply for Multi-signature address ?, If Yes apart from privacy what is the need ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is De facto standard that address should not be reused.

Indeed.

> and even Bitcoin officially emphasis address should not be reused.

There is nothing official, anywhere, in Bitcoin.

> Does the same condition apply for Multi-signature address ?

Yes.

> If Yes apart from privacy what is the need ?

Privacy - for you and those you interact with - is pretty much the only reason for discouraging reuse, multisig or not.